# How to avoid deadlock when delete/update the same record in the Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a scenario when I play with Postgres.

We have one table with primary key, and there are two concurrent process, the one can update record, another process can delete record.

Now we are facing deadlock, when two processes play with update/delete the same record in the table.

I google how to avoid deadlock, someone says to use "SELECT FOR UPDATE".

Suppose there are two statements as following

```
update table_A set name='aaaa' where cid=1;

delete table_A where cid=1;
```

My question is,
(1) Do I need to add "SELECT FOR UPDATE" to both statements or just one statement in order to avoid deadlock?

(2) Could you give a complete example how to add "SELECT FOR UPDATE" ? I mean, what does it look like after you add "SELECT FOR UPDATE"? I never do it before, I want to learn how to add it.

Comment: Did you try reading the PostgreSQL documentation?

Comment: "*Now we are facing deadlock*" - are you? One of the processes wins, the other transaction will fail. What SQL exactly are you executing, are you using explicit transactions?

Comment: Those two statements cannot directly deadlock.  They would need to part of larger transactions with more statements than just those to deadlock.  How the deadlock can be avoided would depend on what those larger transactions are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` locks the selected rows so that any other transaction can neither perform an update nor a `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` on these rows. These transactions must wait until the transaction with the first `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` releases the lock on the rows again.

If `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` is the first statement in all transactions, no deadlock can occur. Because no transaction can lock other lines, which could be used in the further course of other transactions.

So your two transactions should look like this:

```
BEGIN;
SELECT * FROM table_A WHERE cid = 1 FOR UPDATE;
-- some other statements
UPDATE table_A SET name = 'aaaa' WHERE cid = 1;
END;
```

and:

```
BEGIN;
SELECT * FROM table_A WHERE cid = 1 FOR UPDATE;
-- some other statements
DELETE FROM table_A WHERE cid = 1;
END;
```

Comment: Once a process has locked the specific row, at this moment, another process wants to lock the same row, it won't get lock, I am wondering if Postgres has mechanism to retry for a few of times ?

Comment: It doesn‘t retry. It waits until the lock is freed and continues.